# Car Head Unit LCD LVDS to HDMI

Tags: automotive, hdmi, lvds, tft

I've recently picked up a head unit for my car and I am trying to get a HDMI signal to it. I've taken it apart and had a look at the hardware, and it seems to be using a single ribbon cable to drive everything.

[image]

I then managed to find the schematics online for it, and it's using LVDS to drive it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The part number of the LCD screen seems to be YA101B6042-C6.

Can anyone suggest a driver board that would be suitable for me to use? Of course, I will most likely need to build my own breakout PCB so I can route the FPC ribbon to the correct pins as well as design a switching circuit so I can switch between the HDMI input and original car head unit input, but for getting this project underway a driver board would be good for a place to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to add a HDMI input for? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: Put a video game console in my car. Of course the final design will need to be super low-latency, but I can work on that that afterwards once I figure out what type of driver is required and get a grasp on working with LVDS.

Comment: Latency will not be an issue, the conversion from pixels on one interface to another does not take many microseconds. The problem is that the panel has a single native format it runs at, so you must get the console to output that. They may not like to output custom resolutions like a PC can. Another issue is if the console uses HDCP. You can't buy HDMI chips that support HDCP encryption so you won't get any picture. So getting HDMI converted to LVDS is the smallest problem.

Comment: The Android Pie system the head unit is running should be able to tell me the exact resolution it's running at. I will figure out how to get that information from it and add it to the main question. The game console does not use HDCP so it should be fine.

Comment: Okay, I have added a picture of the screen resolution. The screen size itself seems to be 10 inches (which I measured with a ruler) and not 5.6 like the Android app has detected.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT AN ADVERTISEMENT**

An RTD2662 board may be suitable for you *(I'll not give any links here, you can find the board from some online suppliers)*. It accepts HDMI and VGA as input and outputs 1- or 2-channel LVDS signals. A lot of pre-compiled firmware files for different resolutions are also available for that board. But the only way to upload a flash file into that board is to use the I²C lines placed on the VGA connector. So you'll need also a USB-to-I²C converter (e.g. FT232H). There is a few open-source/free flash programming software available online.

**NOT AN ADVERTISEMENT**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check it out. I do have an I2C programmer so that will be okay.

Comment: After doing some deep searching, I managed to find the exact LCD which is used. This is it here.

https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a21wu.10013406.0.0.30686f0cNBH53i&id=625350262321

What I will try and do is contact the seller ask ask if they have a driver board for it. From there, I can get the information based off of it that I need.